# TStringList CustomSort method in FreePascal

Tags: components, freepascal, lazarus

What am I doign wrong with the following code

```
function CompareFloat(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
```

and I call it as :

```
var
   SL :TstringList;

SL.CustomSort(CompareFloat);
//SL.CustomSort(@CompareFloat); // Tried this one also
```

The first function call 'SL.CustomSort(CompareFloat)' retrieves that error from compiler "Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "CompareFloat"

Second function call 'SL.CustomSort(@CompareFloat)' retrieves that error from compiler Error: Only class methods can be referred with class references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SL.CustomSort(CompareFloat);` works if you add `{$mode delphi}` directive to somewhere to the beginning of a unit.

However `SL.CustomSort(@CompareFloat);` should work fine. Make sure the error message is not caused by something else.

Example:

```
program Project1;

//{$mode delphi}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

function CompareFloat(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrToInt(List[Index1]) - StrToInt(List[Index2]);
end;

var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('3');
    SL.Add('2');
    SL.Add('1');
    SL.CustomSort(@CompareFloat);
    //SL.CustomSort(CompareFloat);
    Writeln(SL[0], SL[1], SL[2]);
    Readln;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: OK thanks it works for the stringlist created from scratch otherwise as you pointed out flaw is somewhere else in the code. What exactly means with index1 and index2 in that callback function, index1=current iterator location and index2 subsequent iterator location ??

Comment: CustomSort uses QuickSort algorithm. So every time sort needs to compare two elements it will call the CompareFloat function and it will be called multiple times during sort process. Index1 and Index2 are just the indices of the elements to be compared.